# Devising a sparse array rule

Tags: sparse-arrays, rule

Suppose I have a matrix

```
A={{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

that defines the positions of non-zero values in a sparse array:

```
S=SparseArray[Table[p1 = A[[i, 1]]; p2 = A[[i, 2]]; {p1, p2} -> 77, {i, Dimensions[A][[1]]}]];
ArrayRules@S
{{1, 2} -> 77, {3, 4} -> 77, {_, _} -> 0}
```

Is it possible to construct such a sparse array without explicitly building the table of correspondence, by using a single rule that extracts the positions of non-zero elements from matrix A? Mathematica documentation shows examples of such rules, e.g.

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] <= 1 -> -2 + 3 Abs[i - j]}, {5,5}]
```

How should a similar rule be devised for my case? Thank you!

Comment: `SparseArray[A -> 77]` ?

Comment: @SimonWoods So simple?! Thank you very much, it was exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) shows this form:

> *SparseArray[{pos1, pos2, ...} -> {val1, val2, ...}]*

The list of positions is what you have in `A`, so you could do something like:

```
SparseArray[A -> {77, 88}] // ArrayRules
(* {{1, 2} -> 77, {3, 4} -> 88, {_, _} -> 0} *)
```

If the values are all the same, as in your example, you can supply just the single value rather than a list:

```
SparseArray[A -> 77] // ArrayRules
(* {{1, 2} -> 77, {3, 4} -> 77, {_, _} -> 0} *)
```